# Longtable with multicolumn and multirow issues

Tags: tables, multirow, french, vertical-spacing

I tried to build a "complex" table of a certain size but still have some problems with the multicolumn. As you can see on the attached images, in the table I want to have in the first column "technique" two sub-columns "Methodes au niveau données" and the second sub-column consisting of two lines "sousechantillonage" and " surechantillonage ".

[image]

the code is :

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Résumé des approches de traitement de données déséquilibrées}
\label{tab:RelatedWorkSkewed}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
{\bf Techniques} & {\bf Références} & {\bf Avantages} & {\bf Inconvénients}\\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Méthodes au niveau des données}  & Sous-échantiollonnage & 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Technique simple et largement utilisée dans de nombreux domaines d'applications;
    \item Elle peut être facilement implémenté;
    \item Elle peut aider à améliorer le problème associé au temps d'exécution et au stockage, simplement en éliminant les instances des données de formation.
\end{itemize} & 
\begin{itemize}
\item  Elle entraîne la perte d'informations utiles et significatifs;
\item  Elle peut entraîner des performances médiocres sur des données invisibles.
\end{itemize} \\  \cline{2-4}
    & Sur-échantiollonnage & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Elle peut être facilement mis en œuvre;
        \item Elle n'entraîne aucune perte d'information.
    \end{itemize} & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Elle augmente la probabilité de sur-apprentissage
        \item Elle introduit un coût de calcul supplémentaire et prend du temps de formation.
    \end{itemize}   
    \\  \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Méthodes au niveau de l'algorithme}  & Apprentissage d'ensemble & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Plus de résilience au bruit;
        \item Elle évite le problème de sur-ajustement;
    \end{itemize} 
    & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Elle prend du temps de formation.
    \end{itemize} \\  \cline{2-4}
    & Apprentissage sensible aux coûts & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Technique simple et efficace;
        \item Elle minimise le coût de la classification erronée.
    \end{itemize} & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Les coûts de classification erronée (le coût réel des erreurs) sont souvent inconnus.
    \end{itemize}   
    \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just don't use `\multirow` here. Also, please note that `\bf` is deprecated since a long time. Instead you should either use `{\bfseries <text>}` or `\textbf{<text>}`.

Comment: please always provide a test document that shows the problem.Your title and tagging mention `longtable` but the code fragment that you posted does not use that environment (and doesn't show any package use at all).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions and comments:

- Get rid of the `\multirow` "wrappers" -- all of them.
- To allow additional hyphenation points in hyphenated words, insert `\hspace{0pt}` judiciously. E.g., replace `Sous-échantillonnage` and `Sur-échantillonnage` with `Sous-\hspace{0pt}échantillonnage` and `Sur-\hspace{0pt}échantillonnage`, respectively.
- Fix some spelling errors that will otherwise prevent LaTeX from finding suitable hyphenation points. For instance, replace both instances of `échantiollonnage` with `échantillonnage`.
- Use the machinery of the `enumitem` package to typeset the itemized lists in the third and fourth columns compactly. See the code below for a possible solution.
- Jump headlong into the 21st Century CE by replacing all instances of `{\bf ...}` with `\textbf{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
% allow hyphenation of first words of cells & use ragged-right layout:
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} 

% create a bespoke list-like environment called "myitemize"
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{label = ---, left = 0pt, 
            before = \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
            after  = \end{minipage} }

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Résumé des approches de traitement de données déséquilibrées\strut}
\label{tab:RelatedWorkSkewed}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|P{2.5cm}|P{2cm}|P{4.5cm}|P{5cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Techniques} & \textbf{Références} & \textbf{Avantages} & \textbf{Inconvénients}\\
    \hline
    Méthodes au niveau des données  
    & Sous-\hspace{0pt}échantillonnage 
    & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Technique simple et largement utilisée dans de nombreux domaines d'applications;
        \item Elle peut être facilement implémenté;
        \item Elle peut aider à améliorer le problème associé au temps d'exécution et au 
              stockage, simplement en éliminant les instances des données de formation.
      \end{myitemize} 
    & \begin{myitemize}
        \item  Elle entraîne la perte d'informations utiles et significatifs;
        \item  Elle peut entraîner des performances médiocres sur des données invisibles.
      \end{myitemize} \\  
    \cline{2-4}
    & Sur-\hspace{0pt}échantillonnage 
    & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Elle peut être facilement mis en œuvre;
        \item Elle n'entraîne aucune perte d'information.
    \end{myitemize} 
    & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Elle augmente la probabilité de sur-apprentissage
        \item Elle introduit un coût de calcul supplémentaire et prend du temps de formation.
      \end{myitemize}   
    \\  
    \hline
    Méthodes au niveau de l'algorithme  
    & Apprentissage d'ensemble 
    & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Plus de résilience au bruit;
        \item Elle évite le problème de sur-ajustement;
      \end{myitemize} 
    & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Elle prend du temps de formation.
      \end{myitemize} \\  
    \cline{2-4}
    & Apprentissage sensible aux coûts 
    & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Technique simple et efficace;
        \item Elle minimise le coût de la classification erronée.
      \end{myitemize} 
    & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Les coûts de classification erronée (le coût réel des erreurs) sont souvent inconnus.
    \end{myitemize} \\  
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to have two sub-columns " Méthodes au niveau des données " and "Sous-échantillonnage/Sur-échantillonnage" in the "Techniques" column, for the "Reference" column it is empty, I will fill it in later. Thanks a lot for your help @Mico.

Comment: @SAM - I'm not sure I understand your modified setup. My answer was based on the material you posted in your initial query. If you need a different layout, the answer I provided is almost certainly deficient.

Answer (score 4):

I propose this variant layout, based on `tabularx`. I replaced the default emdash with an endash, which looks better in this context, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e, caption, multirow}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlist[itemize]{label=\bfseries\textendash, nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, after=\vskip-1.5ex}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}
\caption{Résumé des approches de traitement de données déséquilibrées}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{2}{p{2cm}|}*{2}{>{\compress\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
{\bfseries Techniques} & {\bfseries Références} & {\bfseries Avantages} & {\bfseries Inconvénients}\\
    \hline\noalign{\vskip1.5ex}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\itshape Méthodes au niveau des données} \\[1ex]
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Sous-échantillonnage} &
\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
    \item Technique simple et largement utilisée dans de nombreux domaines d'applications;
    \item Elle peut être facilement implémenté;
    \item Elle peut aider à améliorer le problème associé au temps d'exécution et au stockage, simplement en éliminant les instances des données de formation.
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}
\item Elle entraîne la perte d'informations utiles et significatifs;
\item Elle peut entraîner des performances médiocres sur des données invisibles.
\end{itemize} \\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Sur-échantillonnage }&
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Elle peut être facilement mis en œuvre;
        \item Elle n'entraîne aucune perte d'information.
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Elle augmente la probabilité de sur-apprentissage
        \item Elle introduit un coût de calcul supplémentaire et prend du temps de formation.%\vskip-3ex
    \end{itemize}
    \\ \hline
\noalign{\vskip1.5ex}
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\itshape Méthodes au niveau de l'algorithme}\\[1ex]
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Apprentissage d'ensemble} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Plus de résilience au bruit;
        \item Elle évite le problème de sur-ajustement;
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Elle prend du temps de formation.
    \end{itemize} \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{Apprentissage sensible aux coûts} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Technique simple et efficace;
        \item Elle minimise le coût de la classification erronée.
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Les coûts de classification erronée (le coût réel des erreurs) sont souvent inconnus.
    \end{itemize}
    \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]